# What are the consequences of an AD group that has as its member a group, that is already a member (Cyclic references)

Tags: active-directory, groups

I have been looking at an Active Directory that has several thousand groups, where pairs of groups are members of each other.

GroupA has GroupB as a Member.
GroupB has GroupA as a Member.

Oy.  I am trying to think through possible consequences of this circular nesting of groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first of all, be careful that you don't have users that are members of too many groups - this can cause their token to be too large and you end up with things like this:

[image]

And also GPOs will stop being processed, startup scripts, etc.

This isn't directly answering your question, but a bunch of nested groups can definitely exacerbate this problem.  There's nothing inherently terrible about groups being members of one another. i.e. the space-time continuum will not tear open... the only things I can think of is that you might confuse some applications that make extensive use of LDAP queries... things like Exchange, etc.

Comment: @Sahuagin I think the OP, who accepted this answer, read the phrase "There's nothing inherently terrible about it," whereas perhaps you did not bother to read that far.

Answer (score 8):

So, I wouldn't say it's bad, but it can be. There's a few reasons, one of them has to do with scripting. Circular nesting is essentially an "infinite loop" because scripts use a lot of recursive functions. This would obviously cause a script to error out, etc.

Then there is the idea of 'simplification' in AD that circular nesting inherently goes against.

There is a powershell script on technet gallery that helps locate circular nested groups, you can find it here and it'll help in the locating of circular groups:
[Find Circular Nested Groups](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/fa4ccf4f-712e-459c-88b4-aacdb03a08d0)

Two other PowerShell scripts enabling to draw nested groups and so helping to find quickly circular nesting :

[Graph Nested AD Security Groups by MemberOf Back-Link Property](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Graph-Nested-AD-Security-cf692d2e)

[Graph Nested AD Security Groups by Member Property](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Graph-Nested-AD-Security-20aa3fcd)

Answer (score 2):

There are no consequences - at least not as far as Active Directory is concerned.

I've seen deployments with this condition several times; the only thing it breaks is poorly written code that recursively enumerates groups.  And in those cases, it's a simple thing to check for this kind of loop in code and ignore the groups that you've already enumerated, or else just limit recursion depth.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you could take a performance hit generating tokens/calculating group membership.